# How do I establish a WebDAV connection in Gnome 3?

Tags: nautilus, webdav

In Nautilus from Gnome 3, the **Connect to Server** dialog is missing the **Type** field.

How can I establish a WebDAV connection?

[image: Screenshot of the dialog]

Comment: Hi. Could you please tell us what version of Ubuntu you are using and maybe provide a screenshot of the **Connect to Server** dialog? This would greatly help us figuring out what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Andrea,I am using version 12.10, how do I upload an image?

Comment: Please add new information by editing the question.

Comment: To upload the image, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: I can't upload yet sorry

Comment: Try this http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/211/screenshotfrom201212271.png/

Comment: I suppose you are using Gnome Shell, or the Nautilus that come from Gnome 3, because the default Nautilus in Ubuntu 12.10 does not have that dialog. Can you confirm? (If you're unsure, please paste the output of `apt-cache policy nautilus`)

Answer (score 60):

In the **Server Address** field type the following:

```
davs://user@host.name/path
```

The `user@` and `path` parts are of course optional, so, if needed, you can just type:

```
davs://host.name/
```

If you need, you may provide a password as well:

```
davs://user:password@host.name/path
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Such a stupid UI which does not even give a hint which URLs are supported. Used to be much better with the combo box for selection in Gnome 2.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say how long I've been fighting with this, only to find I was missing that trailing slash after host.name. Thanks.

Comment: The help for this in Nautilus is also not helpful because it says to use http:// or https:// for WebDAV

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 12.04, and this simply does not seem to work. It's returning 403: FORBIDDEN all the time.

Comment: @jjmerelo: you might need to authenticate. By the way, please note that 12.04 was released more than 6 years ago and it's EOL now

Comment: Keep getting "HTTP Error: Unauthorized" on 19.04 even though my username and password are provided.

Answer (score 8):

If someone is getting the error "SSL Handshake Failed", then exclude the "s" from davs since we are not using SSL i.e.

```
dav://user@hostname:port/path
```

This took me a while to figure out so hopefully this helps some people out there :).