# WebDAV in Nautilus - connection to OneDrive?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, webdav

There is no official OneDrive client for Linux.
I figured that the easiest way to connect to OneDrive is mapping it by Webdav. In Windows, I can do that by click, drag-n-drop, etc :) See http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/map-onedrive-network-drive

How I can do the same in Nautilus/other way?

Comment: I'm not giving this as a response because I'm not sure it's actually what are you looking for, but hey, maybe it's useful: [here you go](http://www.howtogeek.com/208437/how-to-sync-files-with-your-onedrive-account-on-ubuntu-14.04/)

Comment: I tried this method, but i can't configure this soft (when i try get gui it say that it is still in developmend). So I'm searching for the easiest way :) [this method](http://askubuntu.com/questions/233242/how-do-i-establish-a-webdav-connection-in-gnome-3?rq=1) is not working with onedrive. But thx for help :)

Comment: This is old
See
https://askubuntu.com/questions/958406/how-to-setup-onedrive-in-ubuntu-17-04

Answer (score 1):

After a very long time, I decided to connect via "onedrive-d", not WebDAV :(

Step by step solution:

```
test@test:~$ git clone https://github.com/xybu92/onedrive-d.git
test@test:~$ cd onedrive-d/
test@test:~$ sudo su
root@test:~/onedrive-d# ./install.sh
root@test:~/onedrive-d# onedrive-pref
root@test:~/onedrive-d# onedrive-d start
```

You can read help info by typing:

- onedrive-pref --help
- onedrive-d --help
- And check README.md on "onedrive-d" Github page.

After that, in local path (/home/test/OneDrive), I have all files from OneDrive.