# Issues with "Free OneDrive Client" locking me out of VM

Tags: server, virtualbox

After I installed onedrive for Ubuntu (Following this link here [How to setup OneDrive in Ubuntu 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958406/how-to-setup-onedrive-in-ubuntu-17-04))
I booted up my Ubuntu Server, hosted with DigitalOcean, and I was greeted by a GUI, which I had never seen before Picture of UI,

and my root password reset, stopping me from logging in. I reset the root password, and had it emailed to me, then entering that password, I still could not get it. If anyone has any ideas to help me, I would be glad. My VM is used for a MC server, and I don't want to ditch all this progress because of A stupid error like this

[image]

Comment: What all got installed when you did `sudo apt-get install onedrive`? Did it install a desktop?
`

Comment: The unofficial part would have steered me away.

Comment: @OrganicMarble-
No, after the install, I was able to use the command line for about 12 hours until i launched the VM this morning, and was greeted by the UI.

Answer (score 0):

> After I installed onedrive for ubuntu (Following this link here [How to setup OneDrive in Ubuntu 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958406/how-to-setup-onedrive-in-ubuntu-17-04) ...

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

These instructions are horribly incorrect and wrong.

As the developer of the OneDrive client for Linux, you are installing on Ubuntu 17.x in the non-supported way. Installing via `sudo apt-get install onedrive` is not supported or recommended as this installs an old and unmaintained version.

You have 2 options to install on Ubuntu:

1. Use the Ubuntu PPA
2. Compile from source

These are your only options. Do not use the Universe package. For further details *please* refer to: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md

> Did it install a desktop?

No the package in Universe / PPA does not do this at all.

> No, after the install, I was able to use the command line for about 12 hours until i launched the VM this morning, and was greeted by the UI

This all depends on how you are launching the VM / how did you do your VM install. Did you reboot from the installation media, walk away, and now it was sitting a clean install again ... maybe - totally plausible.