# one drive free client doesn not appear in home directory

Tags: home-directory, aptitude

I wanted to have one drive free client in my home directory and I use it on ubuntu.
Therefore I have used the advise from the following two sources.
https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/using-onedrive-with-linux/
and [How to setup OneDrive in Ubuntu 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958406/how-to-setup-onedrive-in-ubuntu-17-04)

**In both cases I managed to authorize onedrive, this was the message:**

Authorize this app visiting:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=d50ca740-c83f-4d1b-b616-12c519384f0c&scope=Files.ReadWrite%20Files.ReadWrite.all%20Sites.Read.All%20Sites.ReadWrite.All%20offline_access&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient
Enter the response uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient?code=M.R3_BL2.94a533b8-2996-6aef-a782-2f6a0cba3121

Application has been successfully authorised, however no additional command switches were provided.

Please use --help for further assistance in regards to running this application.

**According to the  two main sources it should appear in my home directory.However, it does not appear there. Yet when I type “onedrive” in the terminal it seems as if I have done it correctly:**

Configuring Global Azure AD Endpoints

--synchronize or --monitor switches missing from your command line input. Please add one (not both) of these switches to your command line or use --help for further assistance.

No OneDrive sync will be performed without one of these two arguments being present.

**“Which onedrive “ shows the follwing location:**

/usr/bin/onedrive

Also: Rclone is not an option. I haven’t dealt with the synchronization of one drive yet I am primarily interested why one drive does not appear in my home directory. I am very new to ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

There are only 5 reliable ways to access OneDrive on Linux:

- Via the OneDrive for Linux client - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive - this 'syncs' your data, bi-directional operation, open source and free
- Via the 'onedriver' client - https://github.com/jstaf/onedriver - Native file system that only provides 'on-demand' functionality, open source and free
- Via 'rclone' - https://rclone.org/ - one way sync client, open source and free
- Via 'insync', 'ExpanDrive' - non-free client
- Via the web browser of your choice

The URL's that you have referenced contain poor instructions & details to get you started ... please do not follow those incorrect instructions.